# Cannot fetch json string from php

Tags: android

Hello there i have a php script for registering a user from an android application. I getting an error whereby its failing to convert the string that is coming from the script into json. here is a snippet of my android code.

its giving an error where its saying
Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Here is a the php script

```
<?php
include 'database.php';
//class that will login a royals member based on the username and the password

    class insertRoyalsMember{
    
        private $connection;
        private $connectionFunction;
        
        public function __construct(){
    
            $this->connection = new DbConn();
            $this->connectionFunction = $this->connection->connect();
        }
        //function that will return all the royals members
        public function addRoyalsMember($fullname,$address,$contact,$color,$hobbies
        ,$department,$birthday,$lookingForwardTo,$interests,$profession,$gender,$image){
    
            $filename = "IMG".rand().".jpg";
            $image_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
            file_put_contents('images/'.$filename,base64_decode($image)); 
            move_uploaded_file($image_tmp,"images/$image"); 
            $statement = $this->connectionFunction->prepare("insert into royalsmembers(fullname,homeaddress,emergencyContact,color,hobbies,department,profesion,birthday,interests,lookingForrwardTo,gender,picture)values(:fullName,:homeAddress,:emergencyContact,:color,:hobbies,:department,:profesion,:birthday,:interests,:lookingForrwardTo,:gender,:image)");
            $statement->bindParam(":fullName",$fullname);
            $statement->bindParam(":homeAddress",$address);
            $statement->bindParam(":emergencyContact",$contact);
            $statement->bindParam(":color",$color);
            $statement->bindParam(":hobbies",$hobbies);
            $statement->bindParam(":department",$department);
            $statement->bindParam(":profesion",$profession);
            $statement->bindParam(":birthday",$birthday);
            $statement->bindParam(":interests",$interests);
            $statement->bindParam(":lookingForrwardTo",$lookingForwardTo);
            $statement->bindParam(":gender",$gender);
            $statement->bindParam(":image",$filename);
           
            $result = $statement->execute();
            
            //execute the statement and get the result.......  
            if($result){    
                
            
                $response  = array();
                $response["code"] = 1;
                $response["status"] = "inserted";
                echo json_encode($response);
             
            }else{
              
              
                $response = array();
                $response["code"] = 0;
                $response["status"] = "not inserted";
                echo json_encode($response);
             
            }
          
        
        } 
    }
    
    $fullName = $_POST["fullName"];
    $homeAddress = $_POST["homeAddress"];
    $contact = $_POST["contact"];
    $color =  $_POST["color"];
    $hobbies = $_POST["hobbies"];
    $department = $_POST["department"];
    $birthday = $_POST["birthday"];
    $lookingForwardTo = $_POST["lookingForwardTo"];
    $interests = $_POST["interests"];
    $profession = $_POST["profession"];
    $gender = $_POST["gender"];
    //$image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $image = $_POST['image'];
    //insert the data into the table.......
    $insertRoyalsMember = new insertRoyalsMember();
    $insertRoyalsMember->addRoyalsMember($fullName,$homeAddress,$contact,$color,$hobbies,$department,$birthday,$lookingForwardTo,$interests,$gender,$profession,$image);
    
    ?>
```

Here is a snippet of the activity that is posting the data to the server.

```
final MediaType JSON
                                = MediaType.get("application/json; charset=utf-8");
                        RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
                                .add("fullName", gotFullName)
                                .add("homeAddress",gotFullAddress)
                                .add("contact",gotFullEmergencyContact)
                                .add("color",gotColor)
                                .add("hobbies",gotHobbies)
                                .add("department",gotDepartmentOfService)
                                .add("birthday",gotBirthday)
                                .add("lookingForwardTo",gotLookingForwardTo)
                                .add("interests",gotInterests)
                                .add("profession",gotGender)
                                //.add("password",gotPassword)
                                .add("gender",gotProfession)
                                .add("image",encodeImageString)
                                .build();
                        request = new Request.Builder().url(postUrl).post(formBody).build();
                        //Call call = client.newCall(request);
                        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
                            public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {

                                Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());
                                ResponseBody body = response.body();
                                bodyString = body.string();
                                MediaType contentType = body.contentType();
                                Log.d("Response", bodyString);
                                return response.newBuilder().body(ResponseBody.create(contentType, bodyString)).build();
                            }

                            //fetching json data well
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull IOException e) {

                            } // transmission failure callback

                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull Response response) throws IOException {

                                final String responseString = response.body().string();
                                Log.i("response", "responsemessage:"+responseString);
                                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        pDialog.hide();
                                        try {


                                            JSONObject fetchedObject = new JSONObject(responseString);
                                            int code = fetchedObject.getInt("code");
                                            if(code==1){
                                                Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(v,"User Registered Successfully.",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                                                        .setActionTextColor(Color.BLUE)
                                                        .setAction("DISMISS",new View.OnClickListener(){
                                                            @Override
                                                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                                            }
                                                        });
                                                snackbar.show();
                                                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                                                startActivity(intent);
                                            }
                                            else{
                                                Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(v,"Could Not Register User.",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                                                        .setActionTextColor(Color.RED)
                                                        .setAction("DISMISS",new View.OnClickListener(){
                                                            @Override
                                                            public void onClick(View v) {

                                                            }
                                                        });
                                                snackbar.show();
                                            }
                                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    }
                                    private void displayOnCard(String fullName, String homeAddress, String emergencyContact, String favoriteColor, String hobbies, String departmentOfService, String profession, String birthday, String interests, String forwardto, String picurl) {
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    }
```

Comment: Share the JSON response of your service. I don't know PHP but I see that you are defining an array `$response = array();`

Comment: this is the json response from the script {"code":1,"status":"inserted"}